# Setup for Coin Flip Java in Eclipse

Tags: java

I need help with starting code for a coin toss in eclipse using java, the code needs to contain user input on the coin and call the coin once the code initiates the tossing of the coin.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int choice;
int heads = 1;
int tails = 0;
System.out.print("Please call the toss, heads or tails: ");
choice = input.nextInt();
```

But I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: what have you  tried so far?

Comment: OK, you have the user input.  Next is generating a random number to flip the coin?  You can use `Math.random()`, or use the `Random` class.

Comment: If you search here for 'java coin flip' you'll find a number of similar questions and answers that might give you some useful ideas

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate a random number `0 or 1` and then compare with user input and do the rest based on comparison.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int choice;
System.out.print("Please call the toss, heads(1) or tails(0): ");
choice = input.nextInt();
int randomNum = Random.nextInt(2) + 1;
if(randomNum == choice){
     System.out.print("You win.");
}
else{
     System.out.print("You lost.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int choice;
int heads = 1;
int tails = 0;
System.out.print("Please call the toss, heads or tails: ");
choice = input.nextInt();
if(choice > 1)
{
   System.out.println("Invalid choice");
}
//Get the random number either between 0 or 1 
int randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(tails, heads + 1);
if(randomNum  == choice)
{
   System.out.println("You win");
}
else
{
   System.out.println("You lose");

}
```

Comment: on the area of the code where if (choice > 1) would'nt that cause the code to stop because tails is 0 and if the called 0 or tails would it just stop the code and say 0 is an invalid input

Comment: @Carlos why it would stop at 0 in the condition choice > 1

Comment: Reason I put that condition is you have restrict user input to only 0 or 1

Comment: I was just asking I did not understand that part of the code

Comment: Did you understood now. 

Comment: is there  way to make the answers random like if you put 1 in as your answer you could win or lose

Comment: Didn't get what you mean here?

Comment: like say the user kept putting in the 1 for heads and they kept winning everytime and it did not change how would you randomize the user winning and losing rather than winning all the time

Comment: To answer you question with the logic above it wont happen that the user will win all the time as random number will flip between 0 & 1.

Answer (score -1):

i dont get your question, but:
-start normally, (class, main method, etc) 
-make a variable (int coin, etc)
-use import java.util.Scanner , and int x = scanner.nextInt() to get user input (for what?)
-use math.random for random toss, maybe 0.5 + is heads
-what ever you get = coin 
-refine you question

Comment: I need user input for a guess on when the coin is flipped

Comment: heads needs to be 1 and tails needs to be 0